# strip empty square brackets gives ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, pandas

I'm removing square brackets from my df using this code:

```
test[column].str.strip('[]').astype(int)
```

This works fine as long as there are string values within the square brackets. Ocasionally there are cells having only empty square brackets ([]). These give the following error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

How can I remove all square brackets in my data?

Comment: Your string is simply empty after stripping it. And you can't convert an empty string to int. What should its value be, after all.

Comment: Not sure converting to strings is the right thing to do in the first place. If they are lists, sounds like you should be taking the first element or defaulting to 0.

Comment: Thanks @Markus, that does makes sense. Feeling a bit silly for not seeing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `ast` module.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame({"C": ["[]", "[1]"]})
print(df["C"].apply(ast.literal_eval).str[0].fillna(0).astype(int))
```

**Output:**

```
0    0
1    1
Name: C, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the rows with empty square brackets

```
new_df = test[test[column] != "[]"].copy()
```